# Feature selection using p-values

Tags: p-value, feature-selection

I am working on a regression model and I have 26 features. I want to select a subset of **important/significant** features, not necessarily the ones that help prediction. In other words I want to find a subset of features such that the number of features with p_value < 0.001 is maximized. I found different feature selection methods but none of them use p-values of features.

Comment: So pick all the ones with p_value < 0.001.  I don't recommend it, but I don't really understand your question.

Comment: Do not rely on p-values strongly; they are only indicators not control variables. Use a simple information criterion (eg. AICc) and then slow built up from there.

Comment: This doesn't seem to contain any questions at all. Please ask a question